# Discord.js chocies max value 25

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

There are 30 data in the json file. But the choices section for the discord bot is limited to 25. How can I solve this? I am using Node.js Discord.js.

```js
const currencyData = require("../../json/commands/currency.json");
const currencyChocies = currencyData.currency;
module.exports = {
  deleted: false,
  name: "pricecurrency",
  description: "Currency Price",
  type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
  // devOnly: Boolean,
  // testOnly: Boolean,
  options: [
    {
      name: "currency",
      description: "currency name",
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
      choices: currencyChocies,
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  callback: async (client, interaction) => {
    const currencyName = interaction.options.getString("currency");
    try {
      const data = await fetchCurrencyData("Currency");
      const desiredCurrency = data.find(
        (item) => item.detailsId === currencyName
      );

      if (desiredCurrency) {
        const chaosEquivalent = desiredCurrency.chaosEquivalent;
        const currencyTypeName = desiredCurrency.currencyTypeName;
        interaction.reply(
          "Name:" + currencyTypeName + "  Chaos Price:" + chaosEquivalent
        );
      } else {
        interaction.reply("Nothing Found Currency");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      await interaction.reply("API Error");
    }
  },
};
```

Error:

> TThere was an error: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
> options[0].choices[BASE_TYPE_MAX_LENGTH]: Must be 25 or fewer in length.

I tried sorting but I didn't use it in the structure. Is there a method in Nodejs that can help?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: @CherryDT yes i would do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Check out autocomplete. [Here's](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/autocomplete.html#enabling-autocomplete) the link to the usage guide. After a user submits the command you can verify that the currency they selected is real and is in the list of possible options.

Here's a modified version of their example that fits your needs:

```js
async autocomplete(interaction) {
  const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
  const filtered = currencyChoices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedValue));
  await interaction.respond(
    filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
  );
},
```

Add that to your `module.exports` along with the code that handles the rest of the autocomplete process found in the documentation.

Don't forget to enable autocomplete for your command.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 25 options is the maximum for a slash command.

[Discord docs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yeKn.png)

You can see this [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).